# Is lebesgue measure complete on $\mathcal{B}(\mathbb{R})$?A counter example

Tags: real-analysis, lebesgue-measure

I know that the outer measure is complete on $\mathscr{L}(\mathbb{R})$, and i know   $\mathcal{B}(\mathbb{R}) \subset \mathscr{L}(\mathbb{R})$ and considerer that  $\mathcal{B}(\mathbb{R})$ is the completion of $\mathscr{L}(\mathbb{R})$ ,so the borel measure is not complete.
So i deduce that for some set of null measure exists a subset which doesn't have  null measure (in $\mathcal{B}(\mathbb{R})$),otherwise it would be complete.Can you give me a counter example?

Comment: It's not: indeed $\mathscr{L}(\mathbb{R})$ is the completion of $\mathcal{B}(\mathbb{R})$!

Comment: sorry i edited the question

Comment: You should look for some subset of a null set that is *not measurable*. AFAIK, the existence of such is proved via an indirect cardinality argument. See "Real and complex analysis" by W. Rudin.

Comment: Let $C$ be the cantor set, and let $\mathcal{P}(C)$ the set of subsets of $C$. Since $\mathcal{P}(C)$ has bigger cardinality than $\mathcal{B}( \mathbb{R} )$, there exists some subset $A \subset C$ which is not Borel.

Comment: @Crostul But i thought that the Cantor set belongs only to $\mathscr{L}(\mathbb{R})$ and not  to $\mathcal{B}(\mathbb{R})$

Comment: @Federico The Cantor set is a countable intersection of closed sets, hence it is Borel.

Comment: Ok thanks a lot!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Every measurable subset of a nullset is a nullset itselt - this has nothing to do with completeness.

Completeness means that every subset of a nullset is measurable. The Borel-Sets equipped with the Lebesgue-measure are not complete, i.e. there is a Borel-nullset that has a non-measurable subset.

To see this, observe the Cantor set $C$. From its construction it is clear that $C$ is a nullset and it is Borel-measurable. Since $C$ is uncountable, we have $|\mathcal{P}(C)| = 2^\mathfrak{c}$. However, there are only $\mathfrak{c}$ many Borel-Sets [this is non-trivial and can be proven via transfinite induction], so $C$ has a lot of subsets that are not Borel-measurable.